# ASP.NET Core custom authentication filter for Azure AD token validation

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, azure-active-directory, access-token

I am currently working on a project where I need to work with Azure AD token, which is working fine. I register my application in Azure portal and use the client id in my project and this is working fine with this code (in `startup.cs`):

```
services.AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApiAuthentication(configuration, "AzureAd");
```

and these settings in `appsettings.json`:

```
"AzureAd": {
    "Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
    "TenantId": "35234523452345",
    "ClientId": "25234523452345",
    "Audience": "api://25234523452345"
},
```

I want to token only for one API call but with the above code it will apply on all the API. Can I use a custom filter which will use the Azure token for authentication?

Can someone help me with a code sample?

Comment: Did you mean that you have an api project with several api actions. You integrate azure ad but you just wanna this authentication applied to some specific api but not all the api? If so, I think [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/scenario-protected-web-api-verification-scope-app-roles?tabs=aspnetcore) can help you. Set `[RequiredScope(scopeRequiredByApi)]` on the action.

Comment: And you may refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68763252/azure-authentication-audience-validation-failed/68799358#68799358) to see the sample code if my guess is correct.

Comment: Is there any progress sir? Or any further issue? If you feel my post below can solve your problem, could you pls accept it as the answer to end this case? Thanks for your response  in advance : ）

Answer (score 1):

i found solution for my question, i created a method which will validate azure token, and will return me user name from user claim

```
        public static async Task<string> ValidateAzureToken(string token, AppConfigurationList appConfigurations)
    {
        var tenantId = "Azure Tenant Id here";
        var audience = string.Format("api://{0}", "Azure Client Id here");
        var azureClientKey = "Azure Client secret Key here";
        var myIssuer = string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "https://sts.windows.net/{0}/", tenantId);
        var securityKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(azureClientKey));
        var stsDiscoveryEndpoint = string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "https://login.microsoftonline.com/{0}/.well-known/openid-configuration", tenantId);
        var configManager = new ConfigurationManager<OpenIdConnectConfiguration>(stsDiscoveryEndpoint, new OpenIdConnectConfigurationRetriever());
        var config = await configManager.GetConfigurationAsync();

        var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();

        var validationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
        {
            ValidateAudience = true,
            ValidAudience = audience,
            ValidateIssuer = true,
            ValidIssuer = myIssuer,
            IssuerSigningKeys = config.SigningKeys,
            ValidateLifetime = false,
            IssuerSigningKey = securityKey,
        };
        _ = (SecurityToken)new JwtSecurityToken();
        SecurityToken validatedToken;
        try
        {
            var claims = tokenHandler.ValidateToken(token, validationParameters, out validatedToken);
            return claims.Identity.Name.Split("@")[0];
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw new TGUnauthorizedException("unauthorized domain user", e);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

An ASP.NET Core web application that authenticates Azure AD users and calls a web API using OAuth 2.0 access tokens.

Here you can find the ASP.NET Core samples about JwtBearer. Here the Azure AD samples demonstrate WebApp calling WebApi (also bearer for the WebAPI, OIDC for the App FrontEnd.

Sample Code: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-webapi-openidconnect-aspnetcore

Reference SO Thread: [Azure AD Authentication in ASP.NET Core 2.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57361261/azure-ad-authentication-in-asp-net-core-2-2)

Comment: the sample code is using same code which i am using, but my quesiton is how to write custome token validator

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the `useWhen` mechanism, which lets you apply a type of authentication to a particular condition - eg Path + Method:

```cs
app.UseWhen(
    ctx => ctx.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments(new PathString("/api/mypath")) &&
    ctx.Request.Method != "OPTIONS",
    api => api.UseAuthentication()
);
```

My [experimental .Net Core API](https://github.com/gary-archer/oauth.apisample.netcore/blob/master/src/host/startup/Startup.cs) does this and may give you some ideas. My objective was to write APIs in different technologies in the same way, and to take closer control over OAuth / claims processing.

In a real API it of course makes sense to keep code simple as much as you can, and of course to use proper libraries for any real security / crypto.